# Does this series converge? It seems too simple

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I've seen plenty of discussion on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$, and understand that it does not converge because we can use the conjugate to simplify it to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} >\frac{1}{n} $for $n>4$.

I have a slight variation on that problem:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})}{n}$. My sense is that I can apply the exact same conjugation to obtain $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1} + n\sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$ so that by the p-test with $\frac{3}{2} > 1$, the series converges.

I think that's right, it just seems too simple. Am I missing something, or making a dumb mistake somewhere in here?

Comment: Your reasoning looks ok to me!

Comment: [Some related questions](https://goo.gl/1PEs8W) found by [Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is exactly right. More explicitly, since

$$n\sqrt{n+1}+n\sqrt n>n\sqrt n+n\sqrt n=2n^{3/2}$$

and

$$a>b>0\implies\frac1a<\frac1b$$

It follows that

$$\frac1{n\sqrt{n+1}+n\sqrt n}<\frac1{2n^{3/2}}$$

You may also want to check to make sure that the denominator on the left is never zero or negative.